# Google Merchant Center transfer in Bigquery doesn't return data for yesterday but 2 days ago

Tags: google-bigquery, google-merchant-center

I schedule the transfer to run at around 4 am every day and it usually returns data with product_data_timestamp for the day before. However, today it only returns data with  product_data_timestamp for 2 days ago. I've tried to run the transfer again at 11 am and create a new transfer at 2 pm but it still doesn't return product_data_timestamp for yesterday but 2 days ago. I have never seen this happen before. Do you have any idea why and how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Anna, did you find out why? I see similar behavior for our exports.